# In copper sweat fittings, what is the minimum insert depth?

Tags: soldering, pipe-fitting, copper-pipe

Copper sweat fittings typical come with about 0.5" (or whatever) insert depth for copper pipe?   For example,

[image]

Obviously, it is recommended and best practice to insert the copper pipe that full 0.5".  But, does anyone have recommendation for a minimum insertion depth that is short of 0.5"?

I'm making a loopback for the boiler side of a combi-boier.  I'm short 0.5" on 1" copper plumbing operating at max 180F and 30psi pressure (regulated+TPV).  It's NOT behind a wall, and it will eventually be replaced with something else.  I can fix the problem by simply inserting and sweating the pipe with only 0.25" on each end. Else I would have to buy a teeny tiny section at $70 (for 10ft) today, or $15 (online) and wait a 2-weeks (that's what it took for this piece that's 0.5" too short).

Call me cheap and stupid if you want, but I want to know if 0.25" (about half the recommended depth) is enough for an otherwise properly sweated copper fixture.

Comment: I do not think you are going to get someone here to say "Yes, 1/4" insertion on 1" pipe sweat joint is fine." It will probably / possibly / maybe / could be OK- no one here can confirm that for you. It seems to be what you want to do rather than your other options- so just do it.

Comment: Buy a straight coupling (or two), or a union, rather than 10 feet of pipe. The insert depth is considerably longer than 1/2" on 1" pipe, as well - it's typically close to 1 pipe diameter.

Comment: A sharkbite coupling would probably add enough length to get you a proper sweat joint.

Answer (score 4):

Just get a coupling like you would use to join two long pieces of pipe. Cut your pipe in the middle and insert into the coupling so that you sweat 1/2" on each end into the coupling. $5 instead of $70. With a 2" coupling, that should give you the extra 1" on the end that you need.

In the old days you might have found in Big Orange a scrap bin with cutoffs from people who had pipe cut to size, much the same as lumber scraps, but with the price of copper today, not so likely.

Answer (score 1):

Insert to the full depth.

Clean the pipe and fitting - I use scotchbrite, that fibre green pan scourer, for even “new” pipe and also I do the inside of the fittings. Then flux on both the pipe and fitting, I then find the solder runs around from a single point of contact.

The professionals who use a bag of fittings a day don’t bother, but I have fittings from 5 years ago…

Not inserting to the full depth could mean that the pressure fluctuations over time could break the weaker solder joint.

Comment: Would imagine copper pipe would be able to be moved enough for 0.25 inch.

Comment: I don't disagree with your worry that full depth is safest.  But "recommendations" aren't purely for performance but they are set to accommodate different form of stress (some manhandling pipes) and variability in final joint quality (as you suggested), either due to noobie-ness of tech, need for speed (cost) or just plain sloppiness.  I guess I want to know how much slop has been built into the recommended insert depth.

Comment: What's the definition of "slop" ? How much is too much? How long is a piece of string?